# Does jOOQ translate support Teradata queries to BigQuery queries

Tags: google-bigquery, teradata, jooq

Does  https://www.jooq.org/translate/   support sql query translation from  Terdata DML queries to GCP BigQuery queries ?

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ 3.13 does not yet support BigQuery: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2620, hence the translator on the website cannot do that for you right now. It is definitely among the top candidate dialects to add support for, in the near future.